# How to use AVERAGE inside ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to use the `ARRAYFORMULA` version of

```
=AVERAGE(Linda!B3, Nandi!B3, David!B3, Remmelt!B3)
```

I want the cell to calculate the average value of the entries in that cell from the other tabs (Linda, Nandi, David, Remmelt). I need to use `AVERAGE` and not just sum and division, because I need to deal with the fact that not everyone will enter values in all cells.

I tried using

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(Linda!B3:B, Nandi!B3:B, David!B3:B, Remmelt!B3:B))
```

but then it average over all four columns, not just the four cells I want.

As far as I understand `ARRAYFORMULA` takes an input of type array and displays it over as many cells. So the problem comes down to making `AVERAGE` (or similar) output an array.

Answer (score 6):

Aggregation functions like AVERAGE, SUM and other similar that get as parameters array of values and just return a single value are not able to return array of values by using ARRAYFORMULA.

One alternative is to use the arithmetic operators (+,-,/,*).

If it makes sense to assume that

- all ranges are of the same size
- there aren't blank cells between non-blank cells
- blank cells at the bottom should be ignored

then the following formula could be used to calculate the average:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
   Linda!B3:B+Nandi!B3:B+David!B3:B+Remmelt!B3:B,
   1,
   COUNT(Linda!B3:B)
 )
 /
COUNT(Linda!B3:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some "statistical" and "math" type functions - [AVERAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615), [COUNT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620), [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013), [MIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017), [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) - have corresponding `*IF` and / or `*IFS` variants that, when combined with the [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) function, seem to satisfy this sort of need.

For example, I have a sheet named `monthly` with dates in column A and dollar amounts in column B. I wanted to get the average of dollar amounts for rows where the date was in the year 2021.

Combining [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) and [AVERAGEIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529) worked for me ...

```
=INDEX(AVERAGEIF(YEAR(monthly!$A$2:$A), 2021, monthly!$B$2:$B))
```

Functions of this type include ...

- [AVERAGEIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529), [AVERAGEIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256534)
- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480), [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)
- [MAXIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817) (singular form doesn't seem to exist)
- [MINIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014063) (singular form doesn't seem to exist)
- [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583), [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

Singular forms (`*IF`) match rows based on a single criterion. Plural forms (`*IFS`) match rows based on multiple criteria.

Comment: Are you saying that `=INDEX(AVERAGEIF(YEAR(monthly!$A$2:$A), 2021, monthly!$B$2:$B))` works like an arrayformula?

Comment: @Tedinoz, yep, it's true. But it's not like `ARRAYFORMULA`. Just the first argument of `INDEX` is iterable. And this works like `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Comment: @rh-becker it's doesn't work like expected.