# How to make a formula expand to new rows when new data is added?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've got a set of data, a column of numbers in this case, that I want to automatically calculate moving averages for when new data is entered. Currently I'm doing this by using `=TRIMMEAN($A$2:A2, 0.15)` and applying it down the column. I've tried using `ARRAYFORMULA` to make this work but it doesn't seem to apply down the column when new data is added.
[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zczXCqR-nsbvQ_QdebnAmOJEMsTr9HuqVRbzLP-qTv0/edit?usp=sharing

For example the numbers in the second column are the moving averages of the numbers in the first column. I applied the formula down the column but I'd like it to expand when new data is added into the first column, new data indicated by the red numbers in this case. I've attached a spreadsheet with the included data and my current implementation. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use AVERAGE inside ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113895/how-to-use-average-inside-arrayformula-in-google-sheets)

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user five times.

Answer (score -1):

3 formulas derived from [this site](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/running-average-in-google-sheets-array-formula/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20the%20AVERAGE,use%20more%20than%20one%20formula.) give this
[image]

[test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k4FL-Ty9MbWZjQury9SYC1hV2am33__sEX1cJKaKZbE/edit?usp=sharing)